# How to sort an unordered hash map by value

Tags: c++

I have an std::unordered_map with keys of data type string and values of data type integer. How could I best sort it by value in descending order? In the case of two keys having the same value, (Cameron and William), how can I then sort them by alphabetical order?

How do I go from the example below

```
Chloe --- 144
Elijah --- 51
Cameron --- 485
Jayden --- 390
William --- 485
Natalie --- 207
```

to

```
Cameron --- 485 (C comes before W)
William --- 485
Jayden --- 390
Natalie --- 207
Chloe --- 144
Elijah --- 51
```

Input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Depends on whether you mean an `std::unordered_map` or something else. Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59550578/edit "There's also an edit link below your question") and add a code example of what you mean?

Comment: Also, where are you going to store the sorted items?  In a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>`?  A `std::map<std::string, int>`?  Somewhere else?

Comment: There's no way to reorder a typical hash map like `std::unordered_map`, because its iteration order likely depends on the hash function. The easiest way to iterate over the items in order is just to copy them all into a ordered container like `std::set` configured to compare the second item of a pair

Answer (score 2):

**Assumption:** I assume you're talking about `unordered_map` and getting the elements out of the map and sorting them accordingly because you cannot change the order inside the `unordered_map` itself.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool comparator(const pair<string,int> &p1,const pair<string,int> &p2){
    if(p1.second==p2.second){ // If numbers are same, sort by string
        return p1.first<p2.first;
    }
    return p1.second>p2.second; // Descending order
}
int main(){
    unordered_map<string,int> _map;
    _map.insert({"Chloe",144});
    _map.insert({"Elijah",51});
    _map.insert({"Cameron",485});
    _map.insert({"Jayden",390});
    _map.insert({"William",485});
    _map.insert({"Natalie",207});
    vector<pair<string,int>> arr;
    for(auto i:_map)
        arr.push_back(i);
    cout<<"\nBefore Sorting\n";
    for(auto i:arr)
        cout<<i.first<<" --> "<<i.second<<endl;
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),comparator);
    cout<<"\nAfter Sorting\n";
    for(auto i:arr)
        cout<<i.first<<" --> "<<i.second<<endl;
}
```

---

Output

```
Before Sorting
William --> 485
Jayden --> 390
Cameron --> 485
Natalie --> 207
Chloe --> 144
Elijah --> 51

After Sorting
Cameron --> 485
William --> 485
Jayden --> 390
Natalie --> 207
Chloe --> 144
Elijah --> 51
```

Comment: So you inserted the keys with its corresponding values as pairs inside a vector and then sorted them by value. What is the 3rd argument (comparator) your passing into the sort function? I looked it up on cpp reference but was not able to find any information on it. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: The 3rd argument is the comparison function which determines the order of sorting. For any type of custom sorting order, you need to use a comparator function. Refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-a-vector-in-c/) article and read all 3 sections for a much clear understanding.